# String conditional formatting "equal to" in Excel using Python's xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, string-matching, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have relatively big Excel spreadsheets, where I am applying conditional formatting. However, the content of a cell is relatively short (max 3 letters). So, I need to match exactly a string. 
For example: 'A' should be formatted but nothing more containing 'A' ('ABC', 'BCA', 'BAC', etc.).

I tried different options using 'text' and 'cell' options but I failed miserably. Here is my test case:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format4.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

data = [
    ['ABC', 'BCA', 38, 30, 75, 48, 75, 66, 84, 86],
    [6, 24, 1, 84, 54, 62, 60, 3, 26, 59],
    [28, 79, 97, 13, 85, 93, 93, 22, 5, 14],
    [27, 'BAC', 40, 17, 18, 79, 90, 93, 29, 47],
    [88, 'ABC', 33, 23, 67, 1, 59, 79, 47, 36],
    [24, 'A', 20, 88, 29, 33, 38, 54, 54, 88],
    [6, 'BCA', 88, 28, 10, 26, 37, 7, 41, 48],
    [52, 78, 1, 96, 26, 45, 47, 33, 96, 36],
    [60, 54, 81, 66, 81, 90, 80, 93, 12, 55],
    [70, 5, 46, 14, 71, 19, 66, 36, 41, 21],
]

for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet1.write_row(row, 0, row_data)


worksheet1.conditional_format('A1:J10', {'type': 'text',
                                         'criteria': 'containing',
                                         'value': 'A',
                                         'format': format1})

workbook.close()
```

So, I want to match only one cell. I run out of options/ideas. It seems trivial but I am getting lots of errors that my Excel files are incorrect. Hope someone found solution for this problem.

It's done in Excel 2010 (Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Equal to: type A in textbox).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following XlsxWriter conditional format should work:

```
worksheet1.conditional_format('A1:J10', {'type': 'cell',
                                         'criteria': '==',
                                         'value': '"A"',
                                         'format': format1})
```

Note that, as in Excel, the conditional type should be `cell` and the value should be a string (with quotes).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want Python to match a single character. So for example you want to match 'A' only and reject something like 'AB' and 'AA', before formatting.

For that you need to match character and length.

```
'A' in string and len('A') == len(string)
```

Then you can apply the formatting to the ones that match that criteria.

If you want to use xlswriter conditional_format, according to the [documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_conditional_formats.html), you can imitate equal to by doing:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B3:K12', {'type':     'cell',
                                        'criteria': '==',
                                        'value':    '"A"',
                                        'format':   format2})
```

EDITED error in value (that should be a string as pointed out by @jmcnamara)

Comment: You are right, I could crawl the table and "mark" elements of length 1. And take this table, for applying formatting to those marked elements (cells). However, I was hoping something from xlsxwriter library and .conditional_format(). If there is nothing better, I will use this solution... However, the solution does won't work, if empty cell is modified...

Comment: I see. I think missed your problem. So you want to create a conditional formatting that's only triggered if "A" (let's say) only appears. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's easily done in Excel 2010 (Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Equal to). I have added this into description.